# Array.push is not a function problem in ionic 4 Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, interface

I am working with angular services called device service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

const TOTAL_DEVICES = "TOTAL_DEVICES";

interface deviceInterface {
  ssid : String,
  name : String
}

interface devicesInterface {
  devices : Array<deviceInterface>  
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class DeviceService implements devicesInterface {

  devices : Array<deviceInterface>;

  constructor(private storage : Storage) { }

  addDevice(ssid : String, name : String){
    this.storage.get(TOTAL_DEVICES).then(res => {
      if (res) {        

        this.devices  = res;        
        console.log(this.devices);
        this.devices.push({ssid : ssid, name : name})  

      }else{
        let devices_obj : devicesInterface = { devices : [{ssid : ssid, name : name}] }
        this.storage.set(TOTAL_DEVICES,devices_obj).then(res => {
          console.log('device added');
        })
      }
    })
  }
}
```

I am injecting this service to a page and then calling its addDevice function with proper arguments which all works fine but at run time when trying to add a device it works for the first time and the first device gets added, the next time when it hits if conditions which check if an array exists and try appending to that by pushing another object it receives a run time error.

**ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: _this.devices.push is not a function**

I'm totally stuck at this moment IDE shows no error neither compiler.

Comment: `res` is probably not an array here: `this.devices  = res`

Comment: see the else case TOTAL_DEVICES key has this object 
{ devices : [{ssid : ssid, name : name}] } fetched by res in if case

Comment: console logging res returns this { devices : [{ssid : ssid, name : name}] }

Comment: it json object of type devicesInterface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting this error because `res` is not array. According to your comment, `res` an object with an array property called `devices` in it.

Change it to:

```
this.devices = res.devices
```

You can add the `devicesInterface` interface to the callback parameter to avoid these kind of errors

```
this.storage.get(TOTAL_DEVICES).then((res: devicesInterface) => { ... })
```